# Strings in C Header Files

Tags: c++, string, namespaces, header, std

My header file is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

//using namespace std;

std::string StringMultiply(string Str, int Mult)
{
    std::string Return;

    for (int Index = 0; Index <= Mult; Index++)
    {
        Return += Str;
    }

    return Return;
}
```

Compiling it produces a slew of errors, most of them pertaining to the absence of a `string` datatype.  Uncommenting the `using namespace std;` line fixes it, but I've been told this is bad practice in header files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change

```
std::string StringMultiply(string Str, int Mult)
```

to

```
std::string StringMultiply(std::string Str, int Mult)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to qualify `string` as `std::string` every time you use it if you comment out the `using` line.  Return value for `StringMultiply` is correct but parameter is not.

Personally, I don't understand the advice versus `using namespace std;` - I don't like typing any more than I have to.

Comment: re usual advice "don't put a `using namespace std;` at global scope in a header file", say that someone has ignored that advice and done it, you're using that someone's header, and you have something named `count`. Uh oh, there's also a `std::count` (IIRC). It can be resolved, that's what namespaces are for, but instead of many of the users of the header file doing extra work, it makes sense for the author of the header file to do a little extra work. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

If you replaced `string Str` with `std::string Str` in the parameter list, everything would compile fine. What exactly is the issue?